# How do I know if an object is allocated on the heap using new?

Tags: c++, heap-memory, stack-memory

I want to know if there is any standard library function or other trick by which I can query if a pointer is allocated by the application. Actually I want to do the following....

Suupose I have a function as:

```
void DoSomeThing(SomeObject* pObj);
```

Now to call this function we generally have two choices as follows:

```
//The first method using stack

SomeObject ObjLocal(Arg1,Arg2);
DoSomething(&ObjLocal);

//The second method using heap

SomeObject* ObjUserAllocated=new SomeObj(Arg1,Arg2);
DoSomeThing(ObjUserAllocated);

//But I like to use code like below (saves me some typing)

DoSomeThing(new SomeObject(Arg1,Arg2));
```

But the problem with the third approach is that - the deallocation of the memory is now the responsibility of the called method and here I stuck because I don't know for sure if the object is allocated by the application.

I posted this question here without even Googling it because I am so curious about it and if I get a clean solution that would be a great reward for me...so sorry for that.

If it is not possible to determine if an object is on the heap then how do you gurus would suggest me to implement what I want?

Comment: I don't know how portable it is but you could override `new` (and probably `malloc` though I've never done it myself) and keep track of the addresses of variables allocated. Then when you want to determine if any specific variable has been allocated on the heap, just check your variable cache to see if it exists. This is one crude approach taken by memory leak detection libraries to determine what was allocated on the stack.

Comment: You forgot one syntax: `DoSomeThing(SomeObject const& obj)` can be invoked with `DoSomeThing(ObjLocal(Arg1, Arg2))`. If you actually want to modify obj, then unfortunately C++ does not allow binding temporaries to non-const references.

Answer (score 12):

There is no portable way to determine whether a pointer refers to an object with dynamic allocation, no.

It "saves me some typing" is a very bad reason to choose one solution to a problem over another.  Of the three options you present, the first is clearly the best, as it relies on automatic lifetime management.

That said, if you really are creating an object just to pass to the `DoSomeThing` function, the best option is likely to have `DoSomeThing` take the `SomeObject` by value (or by const-reference); then you don't have to deal with pointers at all.

Comment: Thanks for reminding, actually i was over ambitious and thought i could achieve something that managed languages allows.

Comment: @smit: I'm not aware of any managed language that lets you determine if an object was allocated on the heap or the stack. AFAIK all objects are managed by a GC so being able to know if the object was allocated on the heap or stack is irrelevant.

Comment: @silico I am aware of that,I was talking about the pointer argument passing style.When using managed languages you don't have to worry about any memory management not just this kind of situation whereas I only want to achieve a little memory management so that my methods don't leak memory if i choose to use the third style of passing argument.

Comment: /*I like ' -> ' more than the ' . ' */

Answer (score 3):

> how do i know if an object is allocated on the heap using new or
>   malloc() by the current module?

You can't. Given just a pointer value, there is no portable/reliable way to determine if it was allocated by `new`, by `malloc()`, or if it even points to something on the free store (as your first method shows, the pointer passed may actually point to an object on automatic storage). It may even point to an element in an array. There's no way `DoSomeThing()` can tell.

The way to deal with this is for the users of your function to manage memory for themselves. The first method is what's usually done for something like this, since stack allocation is automatic. For example, a lot of the Windows API (which is for the most part a C API) is done like this, similar to your first method:

```
WNDCLASSEX wndcls;
// Fill wndcls structure
::RegisterClassEx(&wndcls);
```

Here `RegisterClassEx()` doesn't care if my `WNDCLASSEX` is on the stack, on the free store, or as part of an array, as long as I pass in a pointer that actually points to a `WNDCLASSEX`. So your first method really is the preferred way to deal with it in real-world practice.

---

If C support is not required, you can also use references:

```
void DoSomeThing(SomeObject& out) {}
```

An advantage of this approach is that users can't pass a `NULL` pointer, so you don't have to check for it. If `DoSomeThing()` does not modify `SomeObject`, then an even better method is to use `const` references:

```
void DoSomeThing(const SomeObject& out) {}
```

The nice thing about this signature is that it allows this kind of call to work:

```
DoSomeThing(SomeObject(Arg1,Arg2));
```

So you get that "less typing" you want without worrying about memory management.

Comment: Actually "less typing" is not my actual problem,I am c/c++ guy and i am not afraid of it.Code clarity (and also portability) is what i want.I DoSomeThing(new SmoObject(a,b)); is more cleaner style than the first coding style both for the coder and for the observer(some less typing for the coder and less looking above for observer)

Comment: @smit, how is DoSomeThing(new SomeObject(a,b)) any cleaner than DoSomeThing(SomeObject(a,b))? If anything, it seems less clear and memory-leaky.

Comment: @Robert, OK i totally agree with you but as i am talking about passing pointers I have my reasons. If I can detect whether the pointer is allocated using new or malloc() I can design methods which can take argument using both second and third constuct and probably be able to back reference in some of my methods which are designed to do so. Also that would allow me to design a consistent api where user has the freedom to use any of the style and with the added benefit of being highly memory efficient.

Answer (score -1):

First let me say you are almost definitely designing something poorly to run into this situation.

That said, you could do it with some `shared_ptr` abuse:

```
void DoSomeThing(std::shared_ptr<SomeObject> pObj);

SomeObject obj(arg1, arg2);

DoSomeThing(new SomeObject(arg1, arg2));
DoSomeThing(std::shared_ptr<SomeObject>(&obj, [](SomeObject*){})); // Empty deleter written as C++11 lambda (could write out the functor elsewhere if not using C++11)
```

Comment: `DoSomeThing(new SomeObject(arg1, arg2));` is no good.  A smart pointer should always be named and smart pointer temporaries should be avoided.  See the [Boost `shared_ptr` Best Practices](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#BestPractices) for a brief explanation of why, and the linked GotW article for a lengthier discussion of exception safety.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis What temporary are you talking about? This just invokes implicit conversion to a shared_ptr. You're disputing style irrelevant to the topic?

Comment: The best practice is to "avoid using unnamed `shared_ptr` temporaries."  `DoSomeThing(new SomeObject(arg1, arg2));` violates this best practice and thus is inadvisable.  It's best to follow this best practice all of the time, both for consistency, and so that so that one needs not remember when it might be okay to use a temporary and when it is absolutely wrong to use one, especially since it isn't always immediately clear whether a particular usage is right or wrong.

Comment: I understand you are advocating for this best practice but nothing will throw in what I wrote above. It's perfectly safe. And to reiterate, this has nothing to do with the topic at hand.